# Relation does not exist PLPGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a view inside the function using plpgsql which returns the x column of the "small" table which is defined as (x integer,y integer).

```
create or replace function skyline_naive2(dataset text) returns setof integer as
$$
declare 
    fullx text;
begin
    fullx = dataset||'_skyline_naive2';
    execute format('create view %s as select x,y from %s',fullx,dataset);
    return query select x from fullx;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

select * from skyline_naive2('small');
```

It returns **"relation fullx does not exist"**

I understand that it is because there is no fullx relation, but I want to call the view using the variable name.

Any help will be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL for `select` (as you have used for `create`):

```
create or replace function skyline_naive2(dataset text) returns setof integer as
$$
declare 
    fullx text;
begin
    fullx = dataset||'_skyline_naive2';
    execute format('create view %I as select x,y from %I',fullx,dataset);
    return query execute format('select x from %I', fullx);
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
also what can be done if i am returning an integer instead of setof integer? 
foreg
return query execute format('select count(x) from %I', fullx);
but return query only works with setof

Comment: In that case you can declare an integer variable, `execute ... into variable` and return it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `EXECUTE` your dynamic query:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT x FROM ' || fullx;
```

Comment: thanks a lot also what can be done if i am returning an integer instead of setof integer? foreg return query execute format('select count(x) from %I', fullx); but return query only works with setof